# Разные значения нестатического поля в разных потоках

Tags: многопоточность, потоки-данных, c#

Чтобы статическое поле имело своё значение в каждом потоке, его следует пометить атрибутом ThreadStatic. Есть ли стандартный механизм, позволяющий делать то же самое с нестатическими полями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java это `ThreadLocal<T>`. В 4 С# ввели похожую конструкцию: [ThreadLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243%28VS.100%29.aspx#Y114). Для ранних версий можете глянуть возможные решения на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158981/does-c-have-a-threadlocal-analog-for-data-members-to-the-threadstatic-attr).

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл наиболее адекватное решение: Thread.AllocateDataSlot.

Дальше в каждом экземпляре хранится свой слот, и обращение к переменной идёт через него.